# Selenium | Unable to click element under <Span>

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am new to Selenium. I am trying to click a sub menu option which has the following code:

```html
<div class="nav-level nav-level-open">
  <ul id="menu_0af0fc80e81924533d028c395adb60e8">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="" href="?s=jobs&ss=jobs&mode=list">
        <i class="icn-next" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        <span> All Jobs - jobs/ internships/ campus interviews</span>
      </a>
    </li>
```

I am trying to click the button here labelled, "All Jobs - jobs/ internships/ campus interviews". Being a menu, there are multiple such links with the same class name. I would prefer locating the element with Css locator or Xpath. Can someone please help me?

Comment: If I'm getting it right then provide id to span tag and try to select the same using id attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below xpath, i am assuming the string "All Jobs - jobs/ internships/ campus interviews" is not repeated in webpage

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(text(),' All Jobs - jobs/ internships/ campus interviews')]"));
```

you can use above strategy in finding target exlements. if the element's display string is not dupicated in webpage

Comment: Thank  you!
this worked. this is a simple and easy trick. :D
but I had to remove extra space before "All jobs" and the single inverted comma. I made a note of this. Thank you once again. :)

Answer (score 0):

Intall the FirePath Plugin in firefox first and then inspect the button using the firepath. Try with the following code -

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//copy paste the xpath here")).click(); //driver is the reference of WebDriver interface.
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your input. This failed to work though. The xpath i got from this had alphanumeric text.
Mohan Raj S pointed out earlier in the thread that we shud avoid this. Could that be the reason?

Comment: Yes the id of the button is being generated dynamically. So it will always have an unique alphanumeric id each time the page loads. So your selenium webdriver will fail to locate the element if you are declaring the xpath with the id value. The alternative way would be to declare the xpath using the span text like @Mohan Raj S said.

Answer (score 0):

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//ul[@id='menu_0af0fc80e81924533d028c395adb60e8']/li/a")).Click();
```

Comment: @LBar : id value is menu_0af0fc80e81924533d028c395adb60e8. we have to avoid such id's this is alpha numeric. dynamicaly values. it might change when page reloaded.

Comment: driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@class='nav-level nav-level-open']/ul/li/a")).Click();

Comment: @L.Bar -  Awesome !!!
this worked !!!
thank you so much!
Can you please explain the logic here? i want to further my understanding too.

Comment: Ok first of all you need to get some (id/class/name) for object you need to use if its doesn't have one of this try to look at his fathers in tree after you find the identification from him you need to give full path to your object like in the example you can see more examples in: http://www.toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/choosing-effective-xpath/

Answer (score 0):

Try out this:

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
WebeElement element ;

element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[ul[@id='menu_0af0fc80e81924533d028c395adb60e8']/li/a"); 
driver.click;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(text(),' All Jobs - jobs/ internships/ campus interviews')]"));
```

Comment: thank you but this did not work. This is a sub menu item. 
Everything works till i click the main menu item. Once i get past it, i am getting an error which reads:
"Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//span[contains(text(),' All Jobs - jobs/ internships/ campus interviews')]"}"

i tried adding an explicit wait as well. Even that didnt work. Could there be any other reason for this?